# Why are document properties that begin with $ allowed in MongoDB oplog?

Tags: mongodb

In general, mongodb does not allow property names begin with $.

```
eg: db.foo.insert({$bar: 1});
throws:  field names cannot start with $ [$bar]
```

However, in the internals of the local.oplog.rs mongo itself stores operation documents that use $set and $unset keys:

```
eg:

"op" : "u",
"ns" : "wiktory.items",
"o2" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("533022d70d7e2c31d4490d22")
},
"o" : {
    "$set" : {
        "outofprint" : true
    }
}
```

Why is the oplog allowed to violate the property naming rules?

I would like to copy the contents of some oplog.rs.o documents into my own collection for replay at a later time.

Is there a way to convince mongo to let me store a `{"$set": ...}` document in my own collection?

Comment: logically not possible, assume you have this {"$set": ...} and you want to update you document, the query will {"$set": { $set : ...}} that make no sense, its like you when you cant start a variable name with numbers

Comment: `oplog` is a special capped collection, which is used to store the operations that have occurred on the data in the database. Operations are updates/inserts/deletes, which involve the usage of operators such as `$set`, `$push`, and so on. `MongoDB` internally reads and handles data from this collection differently. Hence you would find all the operations stored as data in this collection. This makes sense, since these operations can be applied as is on the other members of the replica set.

Comment: There is no way mongodb would allow you to store database operations in your collection. The question here arises, why would you want to store `MongoDB` operations in your collection?

Comment: As noted by @BatScream, the `oplog` is a special purpose system collection used by the internals of MongoDB's replication implementation. If you want to copy oplog documents to another collection you need to do some transformation for operator field names (i.e replace leading "$" with a valid character prefix).